# Pairing BLE device in windows 8.1 with non-Microsoft stack dongle

Tags: bluetooth, driver, windows-8.1, bluetooth-lowenergy

Here is my problem, I want to develop a .NET application to communicate with a BLE CSR dongle (i.e. uses non-MS stack driver). In windows 8.1, you have to pair the BLE device in the computer's bluetooth settings before the application can use it. It's straight forward, you goto pc settings bluetooth and search for devices. From what I can tell, if you have a dongle that cannot support the ms stack, this bluetooth option disappears in pc settings, and you cannot pair your device using the standard way. I tested this on a machine with both a MS-stack capable dongle and a CSR (non-MS-stack) dongle. If I disabled the MS-stack dongle (in device manager), and noticed the option for bluetooth under pc settings->devices disappears immediately. Once re-enabled, it returns.

So my question is how does one pair a device using a non-ms stack dongle to have the same effect as done under pc settings when using an dongle with the MS-stack?

Many thanks